# Emptying a table and filling with fixtures

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I'm working on a big project (tons of migrations already exist, etc...) and I'm at a point in which I must empty an entire table and then fill it again with ~10 elements. What is the Django approach to this situation? Fixtures? `RunPython`?

Answer (score 1):

## Deleting data from tables (Django)

A default Django-generated migration has nothing to do with populating your table. A default migration changes your database layout, e.g. creates or deletes tables, adds columns, changes parameters of columns etc. (Read until the end on how to use **manual migrations** to delete data from table!)

### Deleting data once

What you want to do is delete **entries** in a table and not delete the whole table. Of course, you could remove the table from your `models.py` and then migrate which would delete the table (if no errors, read next) but that might result in unwanted behaviour and errors (e.g. other models have `ForeignKey`s to this table which would probably prevent you from deleting the table). You have two options:

1. Manually connect to database and run

   ```
   DELETE * FROM your_table;
   ```
2. Use Python to do the job for you. You can open Django shell by executing `python manage.py shell`. Then you have to import your model and run `.delete()`. That would look like this:

   ```
   $ python manage.py shell

   # We are in Django Python shell now...
   >> from app.models import Model_to_empty
   >> Model_to_empty.objects.all().delete()
   ```

---

### Deleting data from tables with manual migration files

If you want to create it as **migration** then you can write a *migration* file yourself. To make sure everything is smooth, run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

first, to migrate any changes that could possible be done in between. Now, create your *fake* migration file like this:

- If your last migration was number 0180, name your file something like `0181_manual_deletion_through_migration.py` and put it in `app/migrations` where `app` is the app that contains the model that needs to be emptied and refilled.
- You can use `migrations.RunSQL` class in your migrations which will execute statement given as argument while migrating.

  Example migration file taken from one of my projects is:

  ```
  from django.db import migrations, models

  class Migration(migrations.Migration):

      dependencies = [
          ('beer', '0001_initial'),
      ]

      operations = [
          migrations.AddField(
              model_name='beer',
              name='beer_type',
              field=models.CharField(default=0, max_length=30),
              preserve_default=False,
          ),
      ]
  ```

  Let's break it down:

  ```
  dependencies = [
      ('beer', '0001_initial'),
  ]
  ```

  This describes the previous migration that altered the model. `'beer'` is the name of the app, `'0001_initial'` is previous migration. Set this to name of model you want to delete entries from and the name of migration should be the last migration.

  ```
  operations = [
      migrations.AddField(
          model_name='beer',
          name='beer_type',
          field=models.CharField(default=0, max_length=30),
          preserve_default=False,
      ),
  ]
  ```

  Inside of `operations` comes what needs to be done. In my example, it was adding a field, thus `migrations.AddField`. Remember I told you about `migrations.RunSQL`? Well, we can use it here like this:

  ```
  operations = [
      migrations.RunSQL("DELETE * FROM your_model;"),
      # run SQL statements to populate your model again.
  ]
  ```

  where instead of a comment you put the SQL statements that will populate the table with entries you want.

When you finish editing the fake migration file, just execute `python manage.py migrate` (**NO `python manage.py makemigrations`!!**).

Comment: I want this to be replicable without human interaction (pretty much like a migration that changes the DB layout is ran without any human typing commands by hand), so this answer won't work. This is why I asked for fixtures or `RunPython`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Before I answer I just need to know something else: Is this supposed to be done on daily basis, every time you make new migration, or something else?

Comment: No, this is a one-time operation that should be run right in-between the migrations. So, let's say I'm on `migration_180.py` right now and let's say I create 20 more migrations in the next few months. I want the developer that will come after me to be able to run `python3 manage.py migrate` and that command to run the 180 migrations, then empty the table and insert the new elements and then run the 20 remaining migrations, so the final state of the DDBB is what it should be expected to be.